# Different schema names in stored procedures for development and production

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, development-environment, production-environment

Schema name is dev in development and prod in production environment. When a stored procedure is created in development using dev schema, What should be the approach to migrate this procedure to prod environment. Below is a sample procedure created, What is the best(ideal) way to change the schema name in SELECT statement to prod from dev before moving it to production environment.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEES(
            DEPT_CD IN VARCHAR2(3),
            RESULT_SET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS


 BEGIN
   OPEN RESULT_SET FOR SELECT * FROM DEV.EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPT=DEPT_CD;
 END

END GET_EMPLOYEES;
```

This procedure will be called from UI, to display the data in UI. In UI same problem is being handled by using configuration files. Please enlighten me what should be the approach for moving stored procedures.
  I have searched but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what should be the approach for moving stored procedures

Don't reference schema names in your code.

If GET_EMPLOYEES is owned by DEV then there's no need to include the schema at all.

If the procedure is owned by a different schema create a synonym for EMPLOYEE table; in development the synonym would point to DEV.EMPLOYEE and it production it would point to PROD.EMPLOYEE.

---

> Schema name is dev in development and prod in production environment

Incidentally, let's call this out for the bad practice it is. I remember having to wrestle with environments configured like this twenty years ago. It was a pain then and it's a pain now. But at least in the past we didn't know any better. There's no excuse for doing it now unless we are developing under a separate schema in the Production database (and that's pretty inexcusable).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to keep schema name same across all environments. If that is not possible you can always use alter session set current_schema=schema_name

Comment: Set `current_schema` won't help in this scenario. It changes the **default schema** when we reference a database object without referencing a schema. Whereas the Seeker's problem is that they have code which explicitly references a schema. Of course they shouldn't use different schema names across environments but unfortunately it is not an uncommon practice.